# EWS Create an appointment to a specific calendar

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm hoping you can help me. I'm looking into using the EWS to automatically manage some calender appointments.

To help me with this I've downloaded the code samples from here:
[MSDN - Exchange 2013 101 Code Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Exchange-2013-101-Code-3c38582c)

They are helpful, however when I run exercise "Exchange 2013 Create weekly recurring appointments on Exchange servers" it is putting the event into a secondary calender I have access to rather than the primary for my user account.

I tried changing the save code to be this:

```
appointment.Save(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar));
```

yet it still goes to the wrong calender. As far as I'm aware my user account shouldn't even have access to the calender it is adding it, but I have it set up as a secondary outlook account.

So this raises the question, I'm connecting to EWS as the current logged on user (my user account). But why is it not saving to my primary calendar? In turn, how does it find the other calenders and decide which it should save against?

Hope you can help, if you need more info just ask :-)

Nik

Answer (score 1):

You need to impersonate as the user you want, find his calender, and then add your appointment. [Microsoft actually has an example that does exactly that.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn722379%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi kat0r, but I don't want impersonate someone else. I am successfully connecting as the current logged on user (i.e. myself) and trying to save to the calender for said person (again myself). But the issue is that it is saving to someone else's calender (who I only have access to because I have set them up as a second account in my outlook).

Comment: Have you checked you are not accidently impersonating that other account? Because I can not think of a way that EWS - which is serverside - uses something from your local Outlook install.

Comment: I'm just as baffled by it as you are kat0r, the logic doesn't make sense to me either. I'm using the following lines of code to extract my current user details:  

            Uri uri = new Uri("http://tempuri.org/");
            ICredentials credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            NetworkCredential credential = credentials.GetCredential(uri, "Basic");

In order to get the logged on user details to pass to the Exchange Service. But when I look at the credentials object the username is blank. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: If you just want to use the currently logged on windows user, you can simply use `ExchangeService.UseDefaultCredentials = true`, and don't have to bother with credentials.

Comment: I get the same behaviour doing this and the long term objective is for it to integrate with a website that uses pass through authentication for domain users so they can save events to their calender via a web portal for scheduling things such as holiday.

Answer (score 0):

Have you take a look at this links:

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633661%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495611%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx
3. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495614%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx

The first link have some code on how to set appointment with attendees. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Jr, I had a look at those but they don't explain the situation I'm having. If it was the other way around and I was trying to use the Delegate approach to save onto someone else's calender it might but I'm not I'm just trying to save on to my own personal calender.

Answer (score 0):

[Enable tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn495632(v=exchg.150).aspx) to see the full SOAP request that is getting sent to the server. There must be something in there that is directing this to the other mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's pretty old question,

but searched for this as well, and this is the solution for who might need it:

you need to find the folder id first, then

```
appointment.Save(CustomCalendarFolder.Id,SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```